# avr-gdb can not understand my input address

Tags: avr, simavr

I use simavr and avr-gdb to debug a .hex file, here is the problem:

```
(gdb) i r pc
pc             0xcd0    0xcd0
(gdb) x/10i 0xc4
   0x8000c4:    nop
   0x8000c6:    nop
   0x8000c8:    nop
   0x8000ca:    nop
   0x8000cc:    nop
   0x8000ce:    nop
   0x8000d0:    nop
   0x8000d2:    nop
   0x8000d4:    nop
   0x8000d6:    nop
(gdb) x/10i $pc-0xc0c
   0xc4:        eor     r1, r1
   0xc6:        out     0x3f, r1        ; 63
   0xc8:        ldi     r28, 0xFF       ; 255
   0xca:        ldi     r29, 0x08       ; 8
   0xcc:        out     0x3e, r29       ; 62
   0xce:        out     0x3d, r28       ; 61
   0xd0:        ldi     r17, 0x05       ; 5
   0xd2:        ldi     r26, 0x00       ; 0
   0xd4:        ldi     r27, 0x01       ; 1
   0xd6:        ldi     r30, 0xEA       ; 234
(gdb)
```

seems that avr-gdb can not understand my input address, and add an offset.

Comment: Just to be clear, the issue is that the second command converted `0xc4` to `0x8000c4`, right?  That is odd.

Answer (score 3):

I'm the author of simavr. Sorry I'm not a member of stackoverflow.

The reason you see these addresses is that gdb/gcc do not handle very well architectures that have overlapping 'address space'. The AVR SRAM starts at 0x000, the AVR Flash starts also at 0x000 and the.... eeprom is ALSO considered to be at 0x000 -- this is the 'harvard' architecture.

So, to make gcc/gdb works, everything is compiled in 'virtual address spaces' by adding an arbitrary constant to these offsets -- So the breakdown is that the Flash is considered to be at 0x000 (fine!) the SRAM is considered to be at 0x800000 and the eeprom at 0x810000.

This allows gcc/gdb to be happy -- however the price to pay is that you will see these wierd addressed when debugging, as gdb firmly believe everything is at these offsets.

The best way to handle this is to ... ignore it! There's very little we can do -- I didn't come up with it, it was rolled into avr-gcc long before simavr started in 2009.

You can see the 'address decoder' for simavr addresses there, perhaps it makes things a little bit clearer.
https://github.com/buserror/simavr/blob/4c9efe1fc44b427a4ce1ca8e56e0843c39d0014d/simavr/sim/sim_gdb.c#L357

Hope this help -- if you have further questions, feel free to pop in to freenode #simavr, or even open and 'issue' on github.